# `[Error] Internal: Uncaught exception thrown of type UnsupportedOperationException (UnsupportedOperationException: null)`

Tags: kframework

I was trying to compile a file with the LLVM backend that previously compiled with the Java backend, and get this warning:

```
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _step: stack subq instruction is too different from dwarf stack size
```

And then when running I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.LLVMRewriter$1.search(LLVMRewriter.java:149)
    at org.kframework.krun.modes.KRunExecutionMode.execute(KRunExecutionMode.java:54)
    at org.kframework.krun.KRun.run(KRun.java:85)
    at org.kframework.krun.KRunFrontEnd.run(KRunFrontEnd.java:95)
    at org.kframework.main.FrontEnd.main(FrontEnd.java:62)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.runApplication(Main.java:118)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.runApplication(Main.java:108)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.main(Main.java:56)
[Error] Internal: Uncaught exception thrown of type
UnsupportedOperationException (UnsupportedOperationException: null)
```

What do these mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The llvm backend does not (yet) support `krun --search`. The only backends that currently support search are the Java and Haskell backends.

As far as the linker warning, I'm not entirely sure what it means, but it has something to do with debug data, so you can probably ignore it and it will not impact the behavior of your executable.

Comment: I’ve been using K for symbolic execution through Z3. I explore all possible transitions and prune those that are not satisfiable. Would this mean the llvm backend isn’t able to do this? My understanding is that the Java backend is going to become deprecated. Will there be an  alternative?

Comment: The haskell backend supports symbolic execution natively, and does  the branch pruning too. The LLVM backend is intended for fast execution